How to do a Hashtag Search in Telegram using Python
Telegram recently added a new feature for searching by hashtags in all public channels at once:
https://telegram.org/blog/message-effects-and-more#hashtag-search
How can I do such search with python? (Telethon, Python-Telegram-Bot, ...)
I found this function on Telethon document:
https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/channels/search_posts.html#examples
But I'm not sure that it is the function that I want!
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.channels.SearchPostsRequest(
        hashtag='some string here',
        offset_rate=42,
        offset_peer='username',
        offset_id=42,
        limit=100
    ))
    print(result.stringify())

I can't set a good offset peer for this function!

OK, I have found the problem...
The offset rate should be 0 to show the results.
import telethon.tl.types
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions

with TelegramClient(session_id ,  api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.channels.SearchPostsRequest(
        hashtag=hashtag, #wanted hashtag without '#'
        offset_rate=0,
        offset_peer=telethon.tl.types.InputPeerEmpty(),
        offset_id=0,
        limit=100
    ))
    print(result.stringify())

